# Is it safe to make a empty field non-empty for a existing database?

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-models, database-schema

Hi, I'm trying to alter my current django project schema, the data migration tool is south. django version is 1.6.9.

It is a existing database so I don't want to mess up with my historical data.

What I'm trying to alter is making a blank=true field non-empty(blank=false) 

here is my model class:

```
class Post(DraftableModel, EditTrackingModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                             verbose_name='headline')

    description = models.CharField(max_length=260,
                                   blank=True,
                                   verbose_name='lead-in',
                                   help_text="260 character limit")
    /*rest of the code*/
```

I want change the description from `models.CharField(blank=True)` to `models.CharField(blank=False)`, which is the default blank value

considering the existence of my database, some of my old Post model do have empty description.
After my migration and change of database schema, will my database be corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

When you try to migrate, django will warn you about those empty fields. so you have few options.

- You can add a default value in your model like `default="Some Default Value"` and django will chose that default value for all empty fields on migration.
- You can just send the migrate request and on the terminal, django will ask you to add an one-off value to be added to all the empty fields.
- Also you can edit the migrate files and add different values for those empty fields based on conditions you have in mind.
- You can write a function to check for all the empty fields for exiting rows and add some data based on some conditions.

**Also i highly recommend to make a backup first. Doesn't matter how small the changes are or how good you are in coding.**